# Laravel form post - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm attempting to post a form to the database, but I'm getting the following error

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message

The form is prepopulated with data and targets a post route. From research, I found out the issue is from posting to a get route, but the route i'm targeting is a post.

**The form**

```
 <form action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}/" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="property_address">Property Address</label>
                </div> <!-- ./col6 -->
              </div> <!-- ./ row-6 -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <select class="form-control" id="property_address" name="property_address">
                    <!--Gets all counties from DB -->
                    @foreach ($properties as $property)
                      <option value={{$property->id}}>{{$property->address . ', ' . $property->town . ', ' . $property->county}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div> <!-- ./ col-6-->
              </div> <!-- ./ row-5  -->
              <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="landlord-name">Landlord Name</label>
                </div> <!-- ./col=6 -->
              </div> <!-- ./ row-4-->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select class="form-control" name="landlord-name">
                    <option value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">{{Auth::user()->name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div> <!-- ./ row 3-->
              </div> <!-- ./col-3 -->
              <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="tenand-name">Tenant Name</label>
                </div> <!-- ./col=6 -->
              </div> <!-- ./ row-4-->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select class="form-control" name="tenant-name">
                    <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div> <!-- ./ row 3-->
              </div> <!-- ./col-3 -->
              <button class="mt-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create Tenancy</button>
            </form> <!-- ./form -->
```

The controller method

```
  //Renders Form
  public function create($id){
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
    $properties = PropertyAdvert::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    return view('/pages/account/tenancy/create', compact('user', 'properties'));
  }

  //Stores data
  public function store(Request $request){
    $Tenancy = Tenancy::create([
      'tenant_id' => $request->user_id,
      'landlord_id' => Auth::id(),
      'property_address' => $request->property_address
    ]);

    return back();
  }
```

The tenancy model

```
class Tenancy extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['tenant_id', 'landlord_id', 'property_address', 'accepted'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
}
```

Routes

[image: Routes]

Comment: This error usually means something is wrong with your route definition. Can you show how do you declare your route in `web.php`?

Comment: The issue is probably with the routing. Please paste your route definitions and also paste the output you get from `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: Added as an image

Comment: In form action replace {id} by {{id}}. Hope will resolve the problem.

Comment: No that isn't working. Hmmmmm

Comment: You need to pass id to your create view.

Comment: I'm using the user id. Which is already passed in via user

Comment: Okay, but it didn't say user previously. Now you have a syntax error. {{$user->id} should be {{ $user->id }}. You are missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: That's just a typo here. It's fine in the file. It doesn't matter what I seem to change, it throws the same error. Is there an issue in the store method?

Comment: To explain the problem in more detail, the id is not rendered which gives you the URL of /account/tenancy/ which you likely only have defined as a GET route. Check your rendered html to verify you have the id appended to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Slash from end of your url in form action :

```
<form action="/account/tenancy/{{id}}" method="POST">
```

Use :  `/account/tenancy/{{id}}` instead of `/account/tenancy/{{id}}/`

and try.

Comment: That solved the issue. Now I get another error. But at least it's progress >Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rentable.tenancies' doesn't exist

Comment: whats your table name?

Comment: your table name should be "tenancies". If not overwite your table name in model. eg protected $table = '***********';

Comment: Tablis name is tenancy. I don't have tenancies defined anywhere afaik

Comment: As I mentioned above overwite your table name in model. eg protected $table = 'tenancy';

Comment: In Laravel Model name should be in singular and table name should be in plural

Comment: Otherwise there is in option to hardcore your table in model as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method. As per your routes, change your method in your form to GET.

Comment: But it's sending data to a database, so it should be a post

Comment: So change your route

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/account/tenancy/{{id}}" method="POST">
```

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tenancy extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tenancy';
    --------------------
    --------------------
}
```

Remove slash after /{{id}}  and make sure you have defined table name in model.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.

Comment: Remove forward slash after {{id}} and try /{{id}}. For table name issue I've share model file as example.